# Cucumber failed scenarios not providing details (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cucumber

When I run cucumber from my Ubuntu server I don't get details on why the scenario is failing. For example here is what I get:

.....
cucumber features/messaging.feature:6 # Scenario: Joe can view his inbox
cucumber features/messaging.feature:14 # Scenario: Joe can send a message
cucumber features/messaging.feature:26 # Scenario: Joe can view a message in his inbox
cucumber features/messaging.feature:35 # Scenario: Joe can reply to a message
.....

Is there something I need to configure or pass to the cucumber command to see the details of the failed scenarios??

Answer (score 2):

[Cucumber Failing with Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026033/cucumber-failing-with-nokogiri)
http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cucumber/page=17

Basically, run cucumber like so:

```
cucumber -f pretty
```

And that should help you track down the problem...